# Laravel Database migration procedure

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am currently using Laravel 5.4. I have a separate database per client. I would like to run database migrations in all my client databases. The database names are in the format of clientdb_{clientid}. I have tried using

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", ["database" =>
 "clientdb_".$client['id'],
"username" => "root","password" => ""]);
```

---

```
 $this->callSilent('migrate', 
[ '--path' => 'database/migrations/clients','--database'=>'clientdb_'.$client['id']]);
```

but I am getting exception called

> [InvalidArgumentException] Database [clientdb_1] not configured.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is configuring the connection labelled **mysql**.  I think what you are really trying to do is configure a new database connection called `clientdb_1`:

```
Config::set("database.connections.clientdb_" . $client['id'], [
    "database" => "clientdb_" . $client['id'],
    "username" => "root",
    "password" => ""
]);
```

Comment: in mysql driver i have configured the db called syncclient. but i would like to access dynamically using config::set aremy clientdb's

Comment: @ganesh Sorry, I don't understand. Is this a new question? Does my answer help with the question you asked initially?

Comment: this is the same question.
scenario::
I have 1db per client. i want to access the client db's without configuring it in the config/database.php file i would like to access all the database is there anyway???

Comment: @ganesh I have answered that question.

Comment: is there anyway i would like to access without configuring in database.php file @Don't Panic

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the database is not configured in your config/database.php file

Comment: yeah i have configured a permanent db in env and database.php. but these are runtime db i would like to access. how to make it possible @Abhishek Vyas